# Calculating exp() of each element in matrix using R

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

how can I take exp() of each element in a matrix? I have `mymatrix = matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), 3,2)` and tried using `res<-expm(mymatrix)` but it requires `mymatrix` to be square. Is there another way to calculate each element so
res is `matrix(c(exp(2), exp(4), exp(3), exp(1), exp(5), exp(7), 3,2)` ?

Comment: `exp(your_matrix)`

Comment: Btw, there is no expm in R. You should be clear about what packages you're using.

Comment: Thank it worked. Not sure why I didn't think of that :S

Comment: I tried the command on the dummie matrix in this example and it works perfect! However when I try it on my bigger matrix I get following error message Error in expm(Matrix(x)) : Matrix exponential requires square, non-null matrix Yes my matrix is not square, but neither is my dummie matrix. I have looked at each cell of the matrix and there are no cells=0.  I'm confused

Comment: You're confusing a matrix exponential with taking the exp() of each element.  These are different operations.  A matrix exponential is defined by a power series, and powers are only defined for square matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res <- mymatrix
res [] <- exp(res)

> res
          [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  7.389056    2.718282
[2,] 54.598150  148.413159
[3,] 20.085537 1096.633158
```

Here you go.